# When do we recycle an bitmap image variable

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas, android-image

In my APP, Activity-A triggers another Activity-B. Activity-B triggers another Activity-C. Now the control return to the Activity-A from Activity-C Via Activity-B. The Activity-A uses the Bitmap image to draw as a background in its Canvas.

### Question:

1. When I move from Activity-A to B, Do I need to recycle the bitmap variable (eg. background.recycle()) in onPause() method ?
2. Assume, I recycled the bitmap variable in onPause() method. Will this be a good approach to avoid OOM error ( keep in mind that the image has to be re-drawn when it comes back to Activity-A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get OOM errors? If not (since your bitmap is not big) then simply do nothing ... The docu says about the recycle method:

> This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called, since the
>   normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no more
>   references to this bitmap.

So there is also a main difference between Android 2.x and Android 4.x. In Android 4 the bitmap memory is no longer managed natively, but is part of the normal java heap and works like every reference works: If the there is no reference anymore, then the garbage collector will collect the bitmap somewhere in the future.

Wherer is the right point to call recycle? Well the right point will be, when the Bitmap is no longer displayed on screen. so onPause could be a possibility, but keep in mind that you have to reload it (async) in onResume. So whats the problem with that approach? Once you have marked the Bitmap to be no longer needed by calling recycle() the bitmap is no longer useable, but probably has not been GC collected yet. So if the user jumps from Activty A to B and will return quickly, it's possible, that you have the same bitmap twice in memory, because the GC has not collected yet the first (recycled) bitmap.

So my tipp is: Try to reduce the bitmap size if you have memory issues. Use less quality bitmap (have a look at Bitmap Options). But I guess you need to try diffrent strategies to find the best working one for your app.

Comment: Actually I have already made the sample size to 2 for the device size 480x320. Finally I have stopped recycle in onPause(). This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

every time you don't need the bitmap recycle it. using 
if method at least to avoid force closing in some cases.

```
if (null != bmp){
 bmp.recycle();
}
```

and i advice you instead of sending the Bitmap between activities get its filename by using intent and pass it through your activities like this you will avoid re-drawing the bitmap in every activity and that will cause OOM for sure.